# Problema al usar Scanner#nextLine(); dentro de un for

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

La cuestión es que quiero ingresar un String que pueda contener espacio(ej: Estados Unidos) y por esa razón uso el nextLine, pero tambien en ese mismo metodo ingreso datos tipo Int. El problema es que al estar dentro de un for en el segundo ingreso se jode por el tema del nextLine.

Ingrese nombre de país: Estados Unidos
Ingrese la cantidad de habitantes: 300

Y después sucede esto:

Ingrese nombre de país: Ingrese la cantidad de habitantes:

Les dejo el código, tenía pensado una posible solución(hacer las cargas por separado pero definitivamente no queda muy bien preguntar 2 cosas por separado).
PD: Supongase que el vector es N cantidad en vez de 5.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problema {
private Scanner teclado;
private String[] paises;
private int[] habitantes;

public void cargar() {
    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    paises = new String[5];
    habitantes = new int[5];
    System.out.println("Carga de paises y cant de habitantes!");

    for(int f = 0; f < paises.length; f++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese nombre de país: ");
        paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
        //teclado.nextLine();
        //paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de habitantes: ");
        habitantes[f] = teclado.nextInt();
    }
}

public void ordenarAlfabeticamente() {
    for(int k = 0; k < paises.length-1; k++) {
        for(int f = 0; f < paises.length-1-k; f++) {
            if(paises[f].compareTo(paises[f+1]) > 0) {
                String auxpaises;
                auxpaises = paises[f];
                paises[f] = paises[f+1];
                paises[f+1] = auxpaises;
                int auxhabitantes;
                auxhabitantes = habitantes[f];
                habitantes[f] = habitantes[f+1];
                habitantes[f+1] = auxhabitantes;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ordenarHabitantes() {
    for(int k = 0; k < habitantes.length-1; k++) {
        for(int f = 0; f < habitantes.length-1-k; f++) {
            if(habitantes[f] < habitantes[f+1]) {
                int auxhabitantes2;
                auxhabitantes2 = habitantes[f];
                habitantes[f] = habitantes[f+1];
                habitantes[f+1] = auxhabitantes2;
                String auxpaises2;
                auxpaises2 = paises[f];
                paises[f] = paises[f+1];
                paises[f+1] = auxpaises2;                   
            }
        }
    }
}

public void imprimirA() {
    System.out.println("Nombres de paises en orden alfabeto y sus habitantes: ");
    for(int f = 0; f < paises.length; f++) {
        System.out.println(paises[f] + " - " + habitantes[f]);
    }
}

public void imprimirB() {
    System.out.println("Nombres de paises y habitantes ordenado de mayor a menor: ");
    for(int f = 0; f < habitantes.length; f++) {
        System.out.println(paises[f] + " - " + habitantes[f]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Problema prob = new Problema();
    prob.cargar();
    prob.ordenarAlfabeticamente();
    prob.imprimirA();
    prob.ordenarHabitantes();
    prob.imprimirB();
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

El problema es que:

```
habitantes[f] = teclado.nextInt();
```

No saca del buffer de `teclado` el cambio de línea por lo que la llamada a:

```
paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
```

Encuentra como primer caracter al cambio de línea y lo toma como una línea vacía

Hay dos maneras de solucionarlo:

#### Consumiendo el cambio de línea con un `teclado.nextLine()` luego del `teclado.nextInt();`

```
for(int f = 0; f < paises.length; f++) {
    System.out.print("Ingrese nombre de país: ");
    paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
    //teclado.nextLine();
    //paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de habitantes: ");
    habitantes[f] = teclado.nextInt();
    teclado.nextLine()  // Esto quitará del buffer el cambio de línea
}
```

#### Leyendo el número como `String` y luego parsearlo a `Integer`

```
for(int f = 0; f < paises.length; f++) {
    System.out.print("Ingrese nombre de país: ");
    paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
    //teclado.nextLine();
    //paises[f] = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de habitantes: ");
    habitantes[f] = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine()); //Esto extrae el número como String pero luego lo parsea como `Integer`
}
```

Cabe resaltar que probablemente en ambos casos sea mejor incluir la lectura del número dentro de un `try catch` ya ambos fallarán en caso se ingrese una cadena que no represente un número.

Comment: Gracias, use la primera opción.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que esta fallando es la lectura de enteros ya que usas el mismo scanner, lo que puedes hacer es usar el mismo nextLine(), y transformarlo a entero.

Cambia esta linea

```
habitantes[f] = teclado.nextInt();
```

por esta linea

```
habitantes[f] = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ya te resolví el problema. Lo que pasaba es que al momento de ingresar valores en la variable de habitantes no limpiabas el buffer y el siguiente campo, que era de texto, lo reconocía como campo no válido. A continuación te dejo el código y los resultados de la consola, espero te sea de ayuda, solamente tienes que ordenar los datos para que se vea mas estético, saludos.

```
package ayuda;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paises_habitantes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] paises = new String[5];
    int [] habitantes = new int[5];

    System.out.println("carga de paises y cantidad de habitantes");

    for (int f=0;f<5;f++){
        System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del pais: ");
        paises[f]=c.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: ");
        habitantes[f]=c.nextInt();
        c.nextLine(); //se utiliza para limpiar el buffer del teclado por variables int aqui estaba tu error
    }
    for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        System.out.println("Mostrando resultados de captura: ");
        System.out.println("Pais: "+paises[x]+" Numero de habitantes: "+habitantes[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Resultados de consola:

> carga de paises y cantidad de habitantes
>   Ingrese nombre del pais: mexico
>   Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: 80000000
>   Ingrese nombre del pais: estados unidos
>   Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: 100000000
>   Ingrese nombre del pais: alemania
>   Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: 60000000
>   Ingrese nombre del pais: rusia
>   Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: 50000000
>   Ingrese nombre del pais: inglaterra
>   Ingrese la cantidad de haitantes: 3000000
>   Mostrando resultados de captura:
>   Pais: mexico Numero de habitantes: 80000000
>   Mostrando resultados de captura:
>   Pais: estados unidos Numero de habitantes: 100000000
>   Mostrando resultados de captura:
>   Pais: alemania Numero de habitantes: 60000000
>   Mostrando resultados de captura:
>   Pais: rusia Numero de habitantes: 50000000
>   Mostrando resultados de captura:
>   Pais: inglaterra Numero de habitantes: 3000000