# Programa en el que nunca se sale del main (bucle infinito(?))

Tags: java

Buenas, he creado un main para un programa y la cosa es que hasta antes de añadir un poco de código me iba todo bien, cuando llegaba al fin del programa terminaba el programa y todo OK. Sin embargo, ahora cuando termina el programa, no termina, se queda como en un bucle infinito del que no sale. Os dejo el main en cuestión:

```
    public static void main( String [] arg)
{
    int empezar = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    boolean solucion = false;
    boolean estado;// para saber a quien le toca jugar
    Tablero tablero = new Tablero();
    boolean continuar = true;
    Scanner sca=new Scanner(System.in);
    while (continuar==true)
    {
        if(empezar%2==0)
        {
            estado=false;
        }
        else
        {
            estado=true;
        }
        while(!solucion)
        {
            if(!estado)
            {
                jugador(tablero);
                tablero.ver();
                estado = true;
            }
            else
            {
                maquina(tablero);
                tablero.ver();
                estado = false;
            }
            if(tablero.esSolucion()=='X')
            {
                System.out.println("FELICIDADES JUGADOR 'X'. HAS GANADO A UN SISTEMA DE INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL");
                solucion=true;
            }
            else if(tablero.esSolucion()=='O')
            {
                System.out.println("HAS PERDIDO. LA MAQUINA 'O' TE HA GANADO. TAL VEZ NO SEAS TAN BUENO COMO UN SISTEMA DE INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL");
                solucion=true;
            }
            else if(tablero.esSolucion()==' ')
            {
                System.out.println("HAS EMPATADO CON UN SISTEMA DE INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL. VAS POR EL BUEN CAMINO JOVEN PADAWAN");
                solucion=true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Desea jugar otra vez? (1=SI//0=NO)");
        if(sca.nextInt()%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("NOS VEMOS EN OTRA OCASION. HASTA LUEGO");
            continuar=false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Perfecto, empecemos de nuevo.");
            tablero = new Tablero();
            solucion = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT:
Os adjunto la operación de la función 'esSolucion()' ya que varios me habéis comentado que es posible que esté ahí el error.

```
    public char esSolucion()
{
    char solucion = ' ';

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(tablero[i][0]=='X'&&tablero[i][1]=='X'&&tablero[i][2]=='X'||tablero[0][i]=='X'&&tablero[1][i]=='X'&&tablero[2][i]=='X')
        {
            solucion='X';
        }
        else if(tablero[i][0]=='O'&&tablero[i][1]=='O'&&tablero[i][2]=='O'||tablero[0][i]=='O'&&tablero[1][i]=='O'&&tablero[2][i]=='O')
        {
            solucion='O';
        }
    }
    if(solucion!='X'&&solucion!='O')
    {
        if (tablero[0][0] == 'X' && tablero[1][1] == 'X' && tablero[2][2] == 'X' || tablero[0][2] == 'X' && tablero[1][1] == 'X' && tablero[2][0] == 'X') {
            solucion = 'X';
        } else if (tablero[0][0] == 'O' && tablero[1][1] == 'O' && tablero[2][2] == 'O' || tablero[0][2] == 'O' && tablero[1][1] == 'O' && tablero[2][0] == 'O') {
            solucion = 'O';
        }
    }
    if(solucion!='X'&&solucion!='O')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(tablero[i][j]==' ')
                {
                    solucion='_';
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return solucion;
}
```

Comment: Por qué haces `sca.nextInt()%2==0`? Si sabes que 0 es No, para que usar el `% ` pudiendo usar un `sca.nextInt() == 0`? Tambien necesitariamos ver las demás funciones como `esSolucion()`

Comment: Parece que el problema lo tienes en esSolucion()...

Comment: En que mensaje se queda el bucle??

Comment: @Leo la pregunta fue marcada como duplicado de [Problema al usar Scanner#nextLine(); dentro de un for](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2803/127), refiriéndose a esa respuesta como respuesta a esta pregunta también. Revisa si tu uso `sca.nextInt()` no tiene el mismo problema comentado ahí.

Answer (score 0):

La manera de estructurar el bucle está bien, lo más seguro es que cuando compara esSolucion jamás entre a un if/else de los que pusiste, se necesitaría ver la función de esSolución o revises si ahí es donde la comparación es diferente.

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código de esSolucion(). He revisado un poco todo, comentando partes de código y tal, pero sigue pasando lo mismo.