# Mi programa de Java no me permite ingresar a un menu

Tags: java

El programa hace la captura d calificaciones y nombres 
Saca los promedios

En la opcion 1 cuando le dijo que no quiero otro proceso no me manda el menú principal

En la opcion 2 no puedo ingresar un método de ordenamiento

En la opcion 3 que es la salida, no me saca del programa.

```
import java.io.*;
public class examen
{
   public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException
   {

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  int numero;
  String [] nombre = new String [10];

  float calificacion1=0;
  float calificacion2=0;
  float calificacion3=0;
  float promedio=0;
  int totalaprobados = 0;
  int totalreprobados = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int otro=0;
  int opcion=0;
  int x=0;
  int cuenta;
  int  y=0;      
  int aux=0;
  String auxnombre;
  int opciones=0;
  int salir=0;

  int contador=0;
  int regresar=0;

  do
  { 
     do
     {
        contador= 1;
        System.out.println("MENU PRINCIPAL \n 1. Captura \n 2. Consulta \n 3. Salida");
        opcion=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        if(opcion==1)
        {
           i=i+1;
           System.out.println("¿Cuall es tu nombre?");         
           nombre[i]=br.readLine();
           nombre[i]=nombre[i].toUpperCase();
           do{
              System.out.println("Dame tu primer calificación");
              calificacion1=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
              if(calificacion1>10)
              {
                 System.out.println("Valor incorrecto");
              }
           }while(calificacion1>10);
           do{
              System.out.println("Dame tu segunda calificación");
              calificacion2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
              if(calificacion2>10)
              {
                 System.out.println("Valor incorrecto");
              }
           }while(calificacion2>10);
           do{
              System.out.println("Dame tu tercera calificación");
              calificacion3=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
              if(calificacion3>10)
              {
                 System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, intentarlo de nuevo");
              }

           }while (calificacion3>10);
           System.out.println("Desea otro proces0? 1.Si 2.No");
           otro= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


        }   
     }while (otro==1);

     if(opcion==2)
     {
        if(contador==1)
        {  

           promedio=(calificacion1+calificacion2+calificacion3)/3;
           if (promedio<7)
           {
              System.out.println("Promedio"+promedio+"Reprobado");
              totalreprobados++;
           }
           else
           {
              System.out.println("Promedio"+promedio+"Aprobado");
              totalaprobados++;
           }




        }

        if(opcion==3)
        {   
           System.out.println(" OPCION NUMERO TRES \n 1. Totales \n 2. Salida "); 
           opciones=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
           if(opciones==2)
           {
              do{     

                 System.out.println("¿Desea salir del programa? 1.SI  2.NO");    
                 salir=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());              


                 if (salir==1 && salir>2)
                 {
                    System.out.println(" Disculpe opcion no valida ");
                 }
              }while(salir==0 && salir>2);
              if (salir==1)
              {

                 System.out.println("Hasta pronto");
                 System.exit(0);

              }
           }
           if(opciones==1)
           {
              System.out.println("Nombre "+nombre);
              System.out.println("El total de alumnos aprobados es de"+totalaprobados);
              System.out.println("El total de alumnos reprobados es de"+totalreprobados);        
           }           

        }

     }
     while(opcion!=3);
  }while(opcion!=4);  

}
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber más del funcionamiento de este sitio. también puedes revisar si la solución esta [pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2803/78) te puede ayudar.

Comment: No consideraría la pregunta duplicada, en este caso no tiene un medio para capturar valores desde la linea de comandos, no tiene declarada la clase Scanner. Creo que aquí se podría sugerir su uso.

Comment: Hola Cristina, primeramente declara   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  y posteriormente después que imprimes el menú principal agrega: opcion= scanner.nextInt(); en lugar de la linea Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); la cual no es necesaria @CristinaGutierrez

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave cuidado. La pregunta actual usa `BufferedReader` mientras que la pregunta que indicas usa `Scanner`. Puesto que apuntan a clases diferentes, tendría más cautela al indicar que son preguntas duplicadas.

Comment: @Jorgesys cuidado al editar las etiquetas. Esta pregunta no indica que se use `Scanner`. La lectura de datos de entrada también se puede hacer con `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Sin ver mucho, el if de la opción 3, está dentro del ámbito del if de la opción, 2, por lo que la opción 3, jamás se ejecutará La opción 3, debe ser paralela, o estár al mismo nivel de la opción 2, es decir, para ejecutarse la opción 3, el if opcion == 2 tiene que cumplirse, fíjate en los cierres de llaves Con calma y paciencia irás detectando las fallas y depurando el enfoque en ese tipo de cuestiones No entendí cuál es el problema del método de ordenamiento en la opción 2, ¿a qué te referías exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente no tienes ordenado tus sentencias.....
Debes mostrarle al usuario las veces que sean necesarias el menú por lo que lo debes poner en el primer do-while.

```
     do{
         //Aqui lo que quieres que se repita en este caso el menú
         System.out.println("MENU PRINCIPAL \n 1. Captura \n 2. Consulta \n 3. Salida");
         opcion=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

         if(opción < 1 || opcion >3)
             System.out.println("Solo ingrese las opciones indicadas");
        do{ 
            if(opción == 1){
               i=i+1;
               System.out.println("¿Cuall es tu nombre?");         
               nombre[i]=br.readLine();
               nombre[i]=nombre[i].toUpperCase();
               do{
                  System.out.println("Dame tu primer calificación");
                  calificacion1=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
                  if(calificacion1>10 || calificación1 < 0)
                     System.out.println("Valor incorrecto");
              }while(calificacion1>10 || calificación1 < 0);
              do{
                 System.out.println("Dame tu segunda calificación");
                 calificacion2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
                 if(calificacion2>10 || calificación2 < 0)
                    System.out.println("Valor incorrecto");
              }while(calificacion2>10 || calificación2 < 0);
              do{
                 System.out.println("Dame tu tercera calificación");
                 calificacion3=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
                 if(calificacion3>10)
                    System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, intentarlo de nuevo");
             }while (calificacion3>10);
             System.out.println("Desea otro proces0? 1.Si 2.No");
             otro= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
           }while(otro == 1)
           if(opcion == 2){
                //aqui no se porque no puede usar un metodo de ordenamiento
                //suponiendo que tienes un metodo que recibe un arreglo y lo ordena yregresa otro arreglo solo haces lo siguiente...
                string[] arregloOrdenado = metodoOrdenaArreglo(arregloDesordenado);
           }
           if(opcion == 3){
             //Aqui va algo...
             if (salir==1) {
                   System.out.println("Hasta pronto");
                   System.exit(0); // o breack
                   opción = 4
             }
           }
     }while( opción != 4)
```