# error al ingresar datos por consola usando la clase Scanner

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

soy nuevo en java estaba practicando condicionales y quize hacerlo mas interactivo pero me ocurre un problema y creo que tiene que ver con la clase Scanner  sucede que la segunda vez que pide ingresar el nombre y el puntaje lo muestra de corrido en una sola linea y si pongo un nombre y luego un numero sale ese error aqui dejo el codigo

```
package Capitulo_4;
//importacion
import java.util.Locale;
import  java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaEstudiante {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //VARIABLES LOCALES
        String name;
        double puntos;

        //CREACION E INSTANCIAMIENTO DE OBJETOS DE LA CLASE ESTUDIANTE
        Estudiante cuenta1 = new Estudiante("joel", 16.25);
        Estudiante cuenta2 = new Estudiante("lesley", 100.00);
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

        //IMPRIMIR
        System.out.print("ingrese su nombre: ");
         name = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ingrese el puntaje obtenido: ");
         puntos = entrada.nextDouble();

         cuenta1.establecerNombre(name);
         cuenta1.establecerPromedio(puntos);

        System.out.printf("Registrando datos de la cuenta1 %n%s%s%n%s%.2f%n%n",
                "   >ingresando nombre: ",cuenta1.obtenerNombre(),
                "   >ingresando puntaje : ",cuenta1.obtnerPromedio());

        System.out.print("ingrese su nombre: ");
        name = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("ingrese el puntaje obtenido: ");
        puntos = entrada.nextDouble();

        cuenta2.establecerNombre(name);
        cuenta2.establecerPromedio(puntos);

        System.out.printf("Registrando datos de la cuenta2 %n%s%s%n%s%.2f%n%n",
                "   >ingresando nombre: ",cuenta2.obtenerNombre(),
                "   >ingresando puntaje : ",cuenta2.obtnerPromedio());

        System.out.printf("La calificacion en  letra de %s es : %s%n",cuenta1.obtenerNombre(),cuenta1.obtenerCalificación());
        System.out.printf("La calificacion en  letra de %s es : %s%n",cuenta2.obtenerNombre(),cuenta2.obtenerCalificación());
    }
}
```

puedo dejar una imagen para que puedan ver el error que sale[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al parecer esta bien, pero veo q cuando pidio el `nombre` no ingresastes nada, siguio y pidio el `puntaje`, pero ahi ingresaste un texto, lo cual dice el error q el dato ingresado no es valido

Comment: Posible duplicado exacto de esta pregunta:    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2803/problema-al-usar-scannernextline-dentro-de-un-for?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que cuando se han ingresado o leído valores numéricos (de cualquier tipo) con los métodos `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`... deja el caracter *\n* o *enter* en el buffer.

Cuando se quiere leer una cadena con el método ‘nextLine()’, esta función inicia la lectura del buffer y lo primero que se encuentra es justamente el carácter de final de cadena  *\n*, es ahí cuando el flujo salta a la siguiente linea, y aunque pensamos que no se leyó nada, si se leyó dicho caracter. En tu caso el problema se extiende y, al continuar genera un comportamiento inesperado.

Para solucionarlo, después de llamar al método de la clase *Scanner* `nextInt()`o `nextDouble()` debes llamar al método `nextLine()`. Por ejemplo justo antes de la segunda introducción de datos:

```
   //CREACION E INSTANCIAMIENTO DE OBJETOS DE LA CLASE ESTUDIANTE
    Estudiante cuenta1 = new Estudiante("joel", 16.25);
    Estudiante cuenta2 = new Estudiante("lesley", 100.00);
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

    //IMPRIMIR
    System.out.print("ingrese su nombre: ");
     name = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("ingrese el puntaje obtenido: ");
     puntos = entrada.nextDouble();

     cuenta1.establecerNombre(name);
     cuenta1.establecerPromedio(puntos);

    System.out.printf("Registrando datos de la cuenta1 %n%s%s%n%s%.2f%n%n",
            "   >ingresando nombre: ",cuenta1.obtenerNombre(),
            "   >ingresando puntaje : ",cuenta1.obtnerPromedio());

    entrada.nextLine(); // Limpiando el buffer 
    System.out.print("ingrese su nombre: ");
    name = entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.print("ingrese el puntaje obtenido: ");
    puntos = entrada.nextDouble(); // Si después de esto volveremos a tener residuo en el buffer 

    cuenta2.establecerNombre(name);
    cuenta2.establecerPromedio(puntos);

    System.out.printf("Registrando datos de la cuenta2 %n%s%s%n%s%.2f%n%n",
            "   >ingresando nombre: ",cuenta2.obtenerNombre(),
            "   >ingresando puntaje : ",cuenta2.obtnerPromedio());

    System.out.printf("La calificacion en  letra de %s es : %s%n",cuenta1.obtenerNombre(),cuenta1.obtenerCalificación());
    System.out.printf("La calificacion en  letra de %s es : %s%n",cuenta2.obtenerNombre(),cuenta2.obtenerCalificación());
```