# Java se salta campos a capturar

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Estoy tratando de capturar múltiples datos con java mediante el uso de `Scanner`, pero cuando inicia la captura de los datos se brinca en automático el primero, mi código es:

```
for (int ctr=0; ctr<3; ctr++){
    System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del producto" + ctr);
    producto[ctr] = data.nextLine();
}
```

Esto me da como resultado:

Ingresa el nombre del producto0
Ingresa el nombre del producto1
 ***- Aqui ya me permite ingresar datos***

Comment: Pon mas código porque me da que heredas un intro de opciones anteriores.

Comment: Es posible que tengas algo en el buffer que te está cogiendo ese primer nextLine(), intenta hacer un flush() antes de entrar al for

Comment: Posible tema duplicado: [Problemas al usar Scanner#nextLine(); dentro de un for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2803/problema-al-usar-scannernextline-dentro-de-un-for?rq=1)

Comment: Querido nat! como estas?, mira, tal y cual como tiene el código a mí me esta tomando todos los datos y el scannner no se saltean ningun ciclo. Te pido muestres un poco mas el código alrededor de ese ciclo for para que podamos darte un approach mas certero.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A falta de ver el resto del código que tienes y sin saber si tienes inicializado el `array` de **producto**, esto es lo que he hecho yo y me funciona perfectamente.

```
package javaapplication11;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] producto = new String[3];

        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++){
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del producto " + ctr);
            producto[ctr] = data.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < producto.length; i++){
             System.out.println("Producto " + i + ": " + producto[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

> Ingresa el nombre del producto 0
>
> Patatas
>
> Ingresa el nombre del producto 1
>
> Leche
>
> Ingresa el nombre del producto 2
>
> Agua
>
> Producto 0: Patatas
>
> Producto 1: Leche
>
> Producto 2: Agua

Comment: No des por sentado lo que tiene, preguntalo y que él lo explique mejor.

Comment: En ningún momento lo doy por sentado. Sólo he puesto una solución sencilla (ya que por ahora no ha vuelto a contestar) y aunque no pregunte directamente, se sobreentiende que al decir "a falta de ver el resto del código..." lo que espero es que él me conteste diciendo cómo lo tiene.

Comment: Pero es posible que por esa solucion sencilla le hayas resuelto su problema pero no entiende el porqué. Simplemente haya esperado una respuesta que le valga y no vuelva por aqui.

Comment: Bueno tras leer todos los comentarios, me han ayudado a resolver el problema y es que una linea antes de abrir el for  para recorrer la matriz tenía una entrada con Scanner de un int, por lo que siguiendo el hilo mas anterior y los comentarios de  Valentín Sánchez Boto fue que me di cuenta que tenía el problema con el buffer y colocando el data.nextLine(); antes del for parece ser que ha quedado resulto.